# Remove specific html entity character from all labels text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, label, html-entities

I have the **warning sign** character which has the value of `&#9888;` in HTML Entity (decimal) and I'm trying to remove it from all checkboxes' label text.

For example, in HTML, one of my input tags is as follows:

How can I, using the $ *(JQuery)* selector, remove the `&#9888;` html entity from those labels.

Here's my attempt :

```js
$('input:checkbox').each(function (index) {
  // I thought by splitting that part and then joining it
  // with an empty string would work.
  $(this).next().text().split('&#9888;').join('');
});
```

```html
<input id='input1'/><label for='input1'>This is the warning sign &#9888;</label>
```

Comment: I see and input without a type="checkbox" in your example.

Comment: Also you are getting the string, splitting it, and joining it, and then doing nothing with that result.  The text() of the field isn't going to automatically update itself to that new value.  You have to set it back if you want it to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the actual character in the split function instead of the html entity.

```js
$('input:checkbox').each(function(index){       
  $(this).next().text($(this).next().text().split('⚠').join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input1' type="checkbox"/><label for='input1'>This is the warning sign &#9888;</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and `slice()`, followed by `join()` to achieve this, assuming this characters are always at end of the string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').each(function(index) {
    var yourText = $(this).next().text();
    var convertedText = yourText.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    console.log(convertedText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='input1' /><label for='input1'>This is the warning sign &#9888;</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the actual HTML character:

```js
$('input:checkbox').each(function(index){       
  $(this).next().text($(this).next().text().replace('⚠',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id='input1' type="checkbox"/><label for='input1'>This is the warning sign &#9888;</label>
```